# Why can't I proxy my emulator WIFI's network?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to Proxy my Emulator to check and verify the networks. However, when I go to the WIFI setting, I can't change my network proxy from None to Manual.

I click and it doesn't respond. Why? How can I get that working?

[image]